# How to get Unicode values of dead keys from mediumraw console keyboard

Tags: linux, keyboard, console

In an application that runs in a frame buffer, I read keys from /dev/tty after having set it to mediumraw mode using

```
int fd = open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR);
...
ioctl(fd, KDSKBMODE, K_MEDIUMRAW);
```

In order to get at the unicode values of the keys representing chars, I do something along the lines of

```
struct kbentry entry;
entry.kb_table = (some combination of KG_* values or 0);
entry.kb_index = code & 0x7f; /* code is the value received by read()ing from /dev/tty */
ioctl(fd, KDSKBMODE, K_UNICODE);
ioctl(kbd->fd, KDGKBENT, &entry);
ioctl(fd, KDSKBMODE, K_MEDIUMRAW);
/* unicode value is now in entry.kb_value */
```

This works quite well, except for one thing: when my keyboard has dead chars, I get those returned as 0x0400, 0x0401, 0x0402 etc. The 0x04 is KT_DEAD, so this looks about right, but when I read the kernel's diacritical table into a struct kbdiacrsuc, I see that that expects actual character codes instead of 01, 02, ... So, how do I get those character codes from the dead keys?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here, as I've figured it out. Studying /usr/include/linux/keyboard.h revealed that there may ony be 6 of those dead characters to take into account. After looking at what's in the struct kbdiacrsuc, I came up with this:

```
    switch (entry.kb_value) {
            case K_DGRAVE: accent = 96; break;
            case K_DACUTE: accent = 39; break;
            case K_DCIRCM: accent = 94; break;
            case K_DTILDE: accent = 126; break;
            case K_DDIERE: accent = 34; break;
            case K_DCEDIL: accent = 44; break;
            default: /* whatever... */
    }
```

Then, doing a lookup with one of these as diacr and another char as base yields the desired accented character.